# Is it possible to add files from different locations into 1 git reposito

Tags: git, github

I am trying to make a git repository of all my config files that I use (vim, VSCode etc)

What I want to have is a repo where all the config files sit. But I do not want to have to go and change the config files in my repo every time I make a change in the ACTUAL config file.

Basically, if I change some settings in my VSCode settings, I want it to be automatically reflected in the settings file in my repo. From there I can just stage the change and push to GitHub. (Something like a soft link?)

What (if any) is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use symlinks to your dotfiles local repository, which [`bbkane/fling`](https://github.com/bbkane/fling) does.

Without any tool, you have the same idea explained in the article "[`~/.dotfiles`](https://dev.to/vibioh/dotfiles-5695)" from [Vincent Boutour](https://github.com/ViBiOh).

> The easiest tools to configure are the ones that rely on a single file on your home directory, that starts with a dot.
>
> That's where the repository takes its name: the famous "dotfiles". You know them: the `.bashrc`, the `.vimrc` or the `.gitconfig`.
>
> In order to keep the file under version control system (Git), but not committing your entire `${HOME}`, the easy trick is using a symlink.
> The file exists in the `${HOME}` folder, so your tool can read it, but the content remains on the folder under version control.

Or you can use [`d3r1n/dotman`](https://github.com/d3r1n/dotman) ([documentation](https://d3r1n.github.io/dotman/#/)), which will take any change with `dotman update`.